# Save image from html2canvas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html2canvas

I want to save the image that is taken from the html2canvas.
Here is code but this doen't work.
This code take the screen shot of the div **mydiv** and then save it.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="jquery.js" ></script>
 <script src="html2canvas.js" ></script>
 <script src="jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js" ></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
 elem = $('#mydiv');
 html2canvas(elem, {

    onrendered: function(canvas) {

        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var output = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        var output = encodeURIComponent(img);
    var cur_path = 'myfolder';

        var Parameters = "image=" + output + "&filedir=" + cur_path;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "savePNG.php",
            data: Parameters
        });

    }
});
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="mydiv">
<h1>Here is some content</h1>
</div>
<button>click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**savePNG.php**

```
<?php
$image = $_POST['image'];
$filedir = $_POST['filedir'];
$name = time();



$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
$decoded = base64_decode($image);

file_put_contents($filedir . "/" . $name . ".png", $decoded, LOCK_EX);

echo $image;
?>
```

This is not work. what is the problem with that code. please help me.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? Is the file created? Does it contain the wrong thing?

Comment: Are there any errors? Have you attempted to debug it in any way? Right now it just looks like you've just copied and pasted most of the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672020/html2canvas-save-image-doesnt-work then posted a question without trying anything yourself. This answer would be a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/2287470

Comment: No error and nor create any file in folder.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors? Is the ajax request successful?

Comment: there is a syntax error, Now I removed in my code.And now this is work.