# Issue in passing base64 encoded image generated using canvas2png using post method

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, base64, html2canvas

I am working in one project in which i have to generate Image from Division. This division is Dynamic container. Admin is adding components to that div.

I am fine to create div width of 300 X 300,  [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCLj4.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCLj4.png)

Also on click of Saving this template to database before form submit i am generating image in following way.

```
var createContainer = document.querySelector("#container");
        html2canvas(createContainer, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                console.log(canvas);
                $("#templateImage").val(canvas.toDataURL());
                console.log($("#templateImage").val());
            },
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        });
```

I am generating canvas of 300 X 300 using [html2canvas.js](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html)

I am getting this base64 value in console but unable to get it in tax box using jqyery.
the base64 value is 
[link to file which contains base64 value](https://jpst.it/GrOh)

**Probblem-1 I am not able to get value in textbox and to next page as well**

Problem-2 I am not able to get this value in next page by POST method

Comment: how do you do this in jquery? show some code

Comment: @heavymetal91 : have updated the question for code of html2canvas

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to print the value in console that means you have value in JS. You can use ajax request to send this value to server, save image on server & return the image path. Now you can set returned path on textbox OR any input fields to access the value on next page via post method.

Comment: Man that i know very well but i need to pass this on simple post method then?. I need solution not alternative.

Comment: Nots sure but may you are getting null values due to server side post/request length limitation OR may be due to some char in string, its not being set on textarea.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan I had used this method in past for the same. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672020/html2canvas-save-image-doesnt-work)