# curl api is replacing + with spaces

Tags: c, http, curl, libcurl

I am trying to do HTTPS POST using curl api in C. I am posting binary data by converting it into base64. However the base64 converted data is getting modified by the curl library. The + symbols in the parameter are getting replaced with spaces. I tried setting the charset as utf-8 and the content type as json. That did not help. Is there a reason why this could be happening? I am on macOS.

Is there a way/option to tell curl to not touch/change my data?

Comment: [May this can help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86729/any-way-to-encode-the-url-in-curl-command)

Comment: At a guess, somehow you sent your data through a URL encoding routine.  A space can be URL-ecoded either as a `+` or a `%20`, so that a good chance where the pluses came from.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp *URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20*

Comment: I am not URL encoding the data. I base64 encode it using something like this (https://www.base64decode.org)

Comment: Show your code...

Comment: Look at this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410515/post-value-geting-plus-signs-removed