# PHP Escaping Quotes Automatically When Using fwrite()

Tags: php, file, escaping, quotes, fwrite

PHP is automatically escaping my quotes before writing to a file using fwrite. I am trying to make a test code page. Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['test'] == 'true') {
$code = $_POST['code'];
$file = fopen('testcode.inc.php', 'w+');
fwrite($file, $code);
fclose($file);
require_once('testcode.inc.php');
}
else {
echo "
<form method='post' action='testcode.php?test=true'>
<textarea name='code' id='code'></textarea><br><br>
<button type='submit'>Test!</button><br>
</form>
";
}
?>
```

When I enter the following into my form:

```
<?php
echo 'test';
?>
```

It gets saved in the file as:

```
<?php
echo \'test\';
?>
```

Why is php automatically escaping my quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not fwrite thats doing it, its because you have [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled.

If you cant disable magic quotes in your php.ini file then you can disable it at runtime, a simple bit of PHP will loop through ALL your input arrays and strip out the unwanted slashes, then you wont need to worry about which POST/GET keys to strip. [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not **fwrite**, its **$_POST**

With these knowledge please find you answer here:

- [Why are $_POST variables getting escaped in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496455/why-are-post-variables-getting-escaped-in-php)

So what you have to do is just small fix:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $code = stripslashes($_POST['code']);
}else{
  $code = $_POST['code'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 0):

You have magic quotes enabled. Disable them in your `php.ini` file (`magic_quotes_gpc=off`) or pass your `$_POST['code']` through [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes).