# PHP variable is messing up img input

Tags: php, stripslashes

In my code I am having PHP write a variable into a text file.

```
$stringData = '<p class="blogcontent">' . $content . '</p>';
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

The variable `$content` includes this `<img src="bpictures/blue.jpg" width="200" />`

But when the variable is written in to the text file this is written into it.

```
<img src=\"bpictures/blue.jpg\" width=\"200\" />
```

And it causes the image not to work when returned into html. I have tried using `echo stripslashes($content);` but that doesn't work, Is there any way that I can write into the text file just the straight code that I have in the variable? I can't find an answer on Google.

How content is made.

```
<span class="addblog">Content (Include img tags from below):</span> <textarea cols="90" rows="50" name="bcontent">  </textarea> <br />
```

On submit.

```
$content = $_POST["bcontent"];
```

There is much more to the code but this is all that effects content for the most part.

Comment: Can we see how you retrieve `$content` and what you do to it, before you put it into `$stringData`?

Comment: did you try `$stringData = '<p class="blogcontent">' . stripslashes($content) . '</p>';`

Comment: Yes, I agree. I feel like magic quotes is on, and then its escaped again, meaning two escapes. But hard to tell unless we see how you filtered the things to begin with.

Comment: And do the quotes in `'<p class="blogcontent">'` get escaped in the file? If not, `$content` does not contain what you claim it does. `fwrite()` does not add slashes.

Comment: Maybe it is when the form submits it adds the slashes? I never thought about that...sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled.

If you can't disable them on the **php.ini**, you can use this function I found here on stackoverflow a while ago, to disable then at run time:

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
}
?>
```

---

Found the original post related to this subject, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440698/php-escaping-quotes-automatically-when-using-fwrite)!

There are other solutions present there, but this was the one I've used.

---

### EDITED

From the above link a simple solution to deal with the `$_POST`:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $content = stripslashes($_POST['bcontent']);
}else{
  $content = $_POST['bcontent'];
}
```

Comment: It didn't seem to work...maybe it is when the form submits and it is stored into the variable.

Comment: Added a simpler solution to deal with the $_POST issue (also came from the provided link).