# Input type and form post adding a slash when i use comments?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have simple input type

```
<tr>            
            <td height="40" class="form-label">Title (required)</td>
            <td><input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="validate[required] form-control"></td>
        </tr>
```

The I post the form, my form post is this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmAddFiles" id="formID" method="post" action="../wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/inc/addb.php" >
```

When I echo the posted data and when it writes to the SQL DB , it adds a slash anytime there is comments in the input type

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
```

Therefore Id I add a input such as    17" Tyres

The echo return as

17\" Tyres

Can I set the form to allow comments in input? for titles such as the above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are $\_POST variables getting escaped in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496455/why-are-post-variables-getting-escaped-in-php)

Comment: Thank you, added stripslashes and works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz try using stripslashes ...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: sorry i didnt see the comment. Please ignore this post