# Strings are escaped after ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

PHP version is *5.6.2*

When sending a JS-object, why do strings end up escaped in PHP?

Here is my JS-code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'POST',
   data: {obj: obj},
   success: function(data) {},
   error: function(req, status, error){},
   timeout: 20000
});
```

All *st'rin'gs* end up like *st\'rin\'gs* in PHP. Of course I can *stripslashes* but what's the proper way of doing this?

**Solution** for everybody in the same situation, who checked and debugged and still can't find a solution: If you're using Wordpress, that's the cause. WP escapes all $_POST-variables automatically and since this AJAX was posted against wp_ajax.php, it was escaped.
I took the easy way out and did:

```
stripslashes_deep($_POST['obj'])
```

Comment: That's not something that happens arbitrarily by itself. The proper approach would be: finding out where and when that happens. Developer tools, payload inspection etc. And yes, the PHP code in question might be more relevant.

Comment: the PHP-code simply does $_POST['obj'] ... I see in Chrome developer tools that the request is sent unescaped. So yes, it seems to happen in PHP, but how?

Comment: Dozens of causes. Not actually running the `PHP_VERSION` you assume. Some code remnants that apply addslashes or premature database escaping on any input variables.

Comment: oh - it seems it's wordpress' fault. It seems to auto-escape all post variables :(

Answer (score 0):

You must check your magic quotes configurations first and do proper changes, please consider reading this post: [Why are $_POST variables getting escaped in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496455/why-are-post-variables-getting-escaped-in-php)

Comment: I've read and debugged. Only now I found out that Wordpress auto-escapes everything, and since this is a WP-plugin...