# How to prevent json-data sent via form to have slashes added?

Tags: php, json, forms, post

Is there a way to prevent JSON-data sent via a form to be escaped with slashes when retrieved with PHP?

I know how to **remove slashes**, but why is it even escaped? Can I prevent it? If I post json-data via ajax there is no slashes added.

Magic Quotes is **not active**, so that is not the problem.

To clarify, my problem is not how to **json_decode** or how to **stripslashes**. I want to know why my json data get slashes added to it when it is posted as a textarea. And if there is a way to to prevent it.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST">
  <textarea name="data">[{"id":85210094,"quantity":1}]</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="POST">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if($_POST['data']) {
  echo '<pre>';
  var_dump($_POST['data']); // string(34) "[{\"id\":85210094,\"quantity\":1}]"
  var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data'], true)); // NULL
  var_dump(json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true)); // array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(85210094) ["quantity"]=> int(1) } }
  echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You could have magic_quotes on, refer this answer : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496455/why-are-post-variables-getting-escaped-in-php

Comment: `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc()); // bool(false)`

Comment: Are you running any other software? Wordpress and similar things are known to proactively escape `$_POST`...

Comment: It is a hard coded normal form, as seen in question. Nothing more nothing less. It might be the case that POSTed forms always add slashes to quotes when received via PHP, I do not know, hence the question. If I check the console, the data do not have added slashes to it in the form data and request header.