# Send code string to the server

Tags: php, post, request

I'm trying to send my code to the server (AJAX code editor):
Example:

`<span class="class">123</span>`

On the server side:

```
$code = $_POST['code']; // Returns me: 123;
$code = $_REQUEST['code']; // Returns me: <span class="class">123</span>;
```

Why **$_POST['code']** returns me stripped result?
Thanks!

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type:       'POST',
                url:            'index.php?option=file&task=templates.save',
                dataType:   'text',
                data:       $("#form").serialize(),
                success: function(data){

                    }
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: You should be testing `if(isset($_POST['code']))`, but that span has nothing to do with AJAX, unless you're just sending useless information that the Client cannot alter to the Server. I would recommend against using `$_REQUEST` anyways, but have no idea why you would get that result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/request-vs-get-and-post

Comment: this has already been answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496455/why-are-post-variables-getting-escaped-in-php
- you have magic_quotes enabled

Comment: Do you understand difference between strip slashes and strip tags, Marina?